# Getting data from excel using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel

I m trying to get data from excel using javascript but my `GetFata(cell, row)` function is not working! Please help
    Here is the code:

```
<script language="javascript" >
  function GetData(cell,row){
  var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
  var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("C://sample.xlsx");
  var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("sheet1");
  var data = excel_sheet.Cells(cell,row).Value;
  document.getElementById('div1').innerText =data;
  }
  </script>

...
...
<input type="button" value="cell(1),row(1)" onClick="GetData(1,1);" />
```

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: I use Google Chrome

Comment: ActiveX only work in IE ... and is disappearing with it, so look for a replacement as this will soon not be possible

Comment: do you mean that I should use another browser?

Comment: Yes, Internet Explorer ... but don't waste time on that as that is a dying technology

Comment: Please provide more details as to what you've tried.  Have you used debugger?  Are you getting any error message?